# why do we need peek() when we have get() in linked list?

Tags: java

why do we need peek() when we have get() in linked list?.while I am studying the linked list I have this doubt. what is difference between them?

Comment: Because `LinkedList` implements `Queue`

Comment: `peek()` is specified by the [`Queue` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#peek())

Answer (score 1):

`get()` requires an index to access an element, `peek()` doesn't. As you can read in the comments the `peek()` also comes from the Queue-Interface.

Simple said the `peek()` internally ([see implementation](https://github.com/srisatish/openjdk/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#L463))

- calls `get(0)` if the list is not empty
- returns `null` if the list is empty

The `get(0)` itself doesn't return `null`, it throws an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[LinkedList - Get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get(int)) vs [Linked List - Peek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#peek())

Take a look at the return values and thrown errors.